How to create button with different gradient in left and right border
How to create rounded gradient pushbutton with dark color areas in left and right side:

Tried style
.gradient-hover-effect {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #3f51b5, transparent) #2196f3;
    font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:xx-large;
    padding: 1em;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color 1s;
    place-content: center;
}

but this produces not so nice button:

Using Google Chrome browser in modern tablet.

The gradient should be from top to bottom.

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Based on what is seen here, here it is:


/* CSS */
.glassbutton {
  background: linear-gradient(#102752, transparent) #2196f3;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:xx-large;
  font-weight: 600;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 21px 1em;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .3s;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.glassbutton:before {
  background-color: initial;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fff 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 20%,  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  border-radius: 125px;
  content: "";
  height: 50%;
  left: 4%;
  opacity: .5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: all .3s;
  width: 92%;
}

.glassbutton:hover {
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 0 3px 15px inset, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 0 3px 5px, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 0 10px 13px;
  transform: scale(1.05);
}
<button class="glassbutton">Eraklient</button>



